# How to get the number of empty cells for each column in spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I'd like to get the number of each column's empty value, so I tried

```
ele_df.where(ele_df['Shipment_ID'].isNotNull()).select('Shipment_ID').show()
```

But it returns me the empty value, it seems it consider the empty value as a non-null value.

```
+------------------+
|Shipment_ID|
+------------------+
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

Could you guys help me with this?

Comment: Use `ele_df.where("nullif(Shipment_ID, '') is not null").select('Shipment_ID').show()`

Comment: Thank you! can i also do this for every column? like using a loop?